# ASP.Net 3.5 webservice Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

**Hello**

I've been following this tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/create-simple-web-service-in-visual-studio-2008-2010-2012/  and added methods of my own and they worked. I've tested them locally and the page seems to look alright, I could select and invoke my methods.

Problem is , when I send the solution for evaluation( as this is homework) the reviewer gets the following error HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. I've searched some time for a universal solution to make it work so I can get a review on my actual work( the methods inside the web service) but it seems I have no success.

I seem to be getting the same error if I move the solution folder from one location to another. I don't really understand what is going on.

I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to ASP.Net, so any site with information would be nice. I've tried the `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: How is your reviewer running webservice - IIS or running from visual studio?

Comment: That is for me to decide, he pretty much just told me to give him  a "step by step" on how to test it. The best I could come up with is make a new solution but I doubt that would be ideal

Comment: if you are running on IIS or if he is running on IIS .. what is the `Default` page for example.. not sure if directory browsing being checked would make a difference or not.. also can you show what your header looks like in the web service that you created.. I am wondering if you didn't change the uri to something other than the default in the namespace...

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean exactly by header, but the the page it redirects me is http://localhost:54071/Service1.asmx when I launch the solution and the namespace [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]. Do I need to change that?

Comment: @dr_T you said reviewer is getting error .. how is he running project ?